# CISCO - organize NAT with 2 WANs, 2VLANs and failover (using PBR / ip SLA )?

Tags: cisco, nat

We have a CISCO 800 series connected to 2 WAN channels, and 2 VLANs. The idea is to have VLAN1 always use WAN1 channel, and VLAN2 use WAN2 channel, but in case of connectivity failure switch to a working channel. Important to say that both WANs use DHCP-assigned IP addresses, so it's not possible to determine next-hop IP address etc.. Default gateways can change from time to time.

I got some problems with realizing this and will greatly appreciate your help:

First some config:

```
interface FastEthernet8   <---- WAN 2
 ip address dhcp 
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!


interface GigabitEthernet0 <----- WAN 1
 ip address dhcp 
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!

interface Vlan1 <---------- VLAN 1
 description LAN interface
 ip address 192.168.244.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip policy route-map VLAN1LAN
!


interface Vlan2 <------- VLAN 2
 ip address 192.168.243.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip policy route-map VLAN2LAN
!
```

Here are the route-maps and access-lists:

```
ip access-list extended LAN1
 permit ip 192.168.244.0 0.0.0.255 any

!

ip access-list extended LAN2
 permit ip 192.168.243.0 0.0.0.255 any

!

route-map VLAN2LAN permit 10

 match ip address LAN2
 set interface FastEthernet8
!

route-map VLAN1LAN permit 10

 match ip address LAN1
 set interface GigabitEthernet0
!
```

Also have this for NAT:

```
route-map VLAN1NAT permit 10
 match interface GigabitEthernet0
!

route-map VLAN2NAT permit 10
 match interface FastEthernet8
!

ip nat inside source route-map VLAN1NAT interface GigabitEthernet0 overload
ip nat inside source route-map VLAN2NAT interface FastEthernet8 overload
```

This configuration works (VLAN1 <--nat---> WAN1 and VLAN2 <---nat---> WAN2) but does not solve the problem of channel breakdown switch.

So I implemented some sla and tracks:

```
track 10 ip sla 1 reachability
 delay down 20 up 20
!
track 20 ip sla 2 reachability
 delay down 20 up 20
!

ip sla 1
 icmp-echo X.X.X.X source-interface GigabitEthernet0
 threshold 500
 timeout 500
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
ip sla 2
 icmp-echo Y.Y.Y.Y source-interface FastEthernet8
 threshold 500
 timeout 500
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 2 life forever start-time now
```

This all works (tracks show channel availabiility), but now how do I apply these tracks to PBRs. Since I do not use

next-hop, and use set interface there is no option to set a track. I would like to do smth like this:

```
route-map VLAN2LAN permit 10 <---- high priority

 match ip address LAN2
 set interface FastEthernet8 track 2
!

route-map VLAN2LAN permit 30  <---- used when track 2 fails

 match ip address LAN2
 set interface GigabitEthernet0 track 1
!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you apply the route-map to a vlan interface you should not have to match on ip addresses in the route-map.

I haven't tested this but if you have IOS 15.4(3)M or later you could try with "match track " in your route-maps to only set the next-hop if the track object returns status ok. So if you have a default route configured it will fall back on that one when the link fails.